# asterisk rejected because extension not found in context - trying to remove +1 from callerid

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I'm trying to remove the +1 from the callerid but I keep getting "asterisk rejected because extension not found in context. Here is my extensions_custom.conf:

```
[from-trunk-remove-plusone]
exten => s/+1NXXNXXXXXX,1,Set(CALLERID(num)=${CALLERID(num):2})
exten => _.!,n,Goto(from-trunk,$[EXTEN],1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use '_' before any pattern, including pattern in callerid.

'!' sign mean "no more search" and ussless after dot(match anything).